# Using this to compare objects (Actionscript 3)

Tags: arrays, events, actionscript, this

I am trying to find the position of the caller of an Event inside the _ar_cards array, however this piece of code won't work. What is wrong?

```
for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        if(this == _ar_cards[i])
        {
            mouseEvent.target.alpha = 0.1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add trace functions in the cycle:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    trace(this.name, _ar_cards[i].name);

    if (this == _ar_cards[i])
    {
        trace("It works!");
        mouseEvent.target.alpha = 0.1;
    }
}
```

And you will see where is the problem.

Comment: I see... But is there any way to do what I was trying to accomplish? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But there are many reasons, why your code don't work. Please, show results of trace functions.

Comment: It seems like `this` reference to `root 1`. But there are only A, B, C objects in the `_ar_cards`. Try this `if (mouseEvent.target == _ar_cards[i])'.